# Flutter with provider pattern: How and where to get async data

Tags: flutter

When using the provider pattern in Flutter, I do not understand how and where to fetch (async) data from the database or an API.

The tutorials seem toconveniently omit this use case which is quite central.

So with something like

```
class ToDo with ChangeNotifier {
     get todos async {
         if(_todos == null) {
             _todos = await MyApi.fetchToDos();
         }
     return _todos;
    }
}
```

Where and how would I actually fetch this data? 
Should I always use a FutureBuilder? Or should it be fetched in some wrapper widget at the top and passed down?

Answer (score 0):

You could fetch the data in the constructor.

```dart
class ToDo extends ChangeNotifier {
    ToDo() {
        _fetchToDos()
    }
}
```

You could also notify listener when the fetch is done.
More information on the [provider package doc](https://pub.dev/packages/provider#i-use-changenotifier-and-i-have-an-exception-when-i-update-it-what-happens).